# How to configure Web Inspector on Windows 7 using iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, web, safari, web-inspector

I have to use Web Inspector on windows 7. 
I have installed safari ( ver 5.1.7) browser on Windows 7 and basically well known about Preference Setting and Develpe menu option. But in develop menu my device is not Appearing. 
Is this possible to use Web inspector with Windows?
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari 5 does not have that feature. You need Safari 6, which is not (currently) available for Windows.

I regularly use `weinre`. It basically runs a webserver that in turn acts as an inspector-enhanced proxy to browse webpages and websites. The inspector can be started by adding a script to your page or running a bookmarklet.

> weinre is a debugger for web pages, like FireBug (for FireFox) and Web Inspector (for WebKit-based browsers), except it's designed to work remotely, and in particular, to allow you debug web pages on a mobile device such as a phone.

To install it, you will need NodeJS and NPM (included with NodeJS). You will also need a WebKit-based browser on the desktop/receiver end (Safari, Google Chrome, or Chromium). It should work on Windows, OSX, and Linux.

- Official page: https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/
- Documentation & Getting Started: https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

[image]

Comment: This tool is amazing… I have no idea why this is the first time I'm hearing about this.